# Why R library is ignoring small numbers?

Tags: r

We are using R library to evaluate expressions. And just found something interesting here.

`2^52+1-2^52 => 1`

`2^53+1-2^53 => 0`

Apparently, 1 gets ignored in the latter case. Why is 53? What happens between 52 and 53? Since this would impact the evaluations, we'd like to know a bit better about what is happening behind the scene and how other talents are dealing with this.

Comment: Well, this is rounding error. Are you surprised that when you are adding 9.007199e+15 and 1 the result is 9.007199e+15 ?

Comment: Why 4.5036e+15 (2^52) works here?

Comment: Have you looked at all at the extensive documentation in the linked duplicate answer?  The short answer is because double-precision floating point numbers typically uses 53 binary bits to store the [mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand). Also try `1/.Machine$double.eps`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes a lot sense.